# Can one lakh recitations of a mantra be done in a week?

Tags: mantras, tantra, yajur-veda, gayatri-mantra, gayatri

I wish to know if it is ok to complete the recitations of the mantra in a week or should the recitations be paced over for a mandala number of days

Answer (score 2):

The number of `jap` (recitation) required for `mantra-siddhi` (Success) is considered to be equal to number of letters (`Aksharas`).

For example: Gayatri mantra has 24 letters, so that 240,000 recitations is recommend. But -

> Akhand Jap vs Anushthana
> If you are planning to do `Anushthana` you may refer this link [Type of Anushthana](http://www.awgp.org/spiritual_wisdom/gayatri/faq/types_of_anusthans).
> [image]

Or [Akhand Jap](http://www.awgp.org/spiritual_wisdom/gayatri/faq/akhand_jap) would be more flexible.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Answers here must be backed-up with "authoritative sources/references". Kindly visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!